# Prove that $E= \{x ∈ R : f(x) > t\}$ is open.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f : R → R$ be continuous and let $t ∈ R$. Define $E = \{x ∈ R : f(x) > t\}$. Prove that $E$ is open.

I am aware that for a set to be open, all its points must be interior points which means that all the points have a neighborhood such that the neighborhood is in the set E. However, I really do not know how to prove that all the points are interior. 
I was thinking that either induction would need to be used or a contradiction, but I am unsure how to do either. 
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Try showing complement of $E$ is closed.

Comment: I'm assuming you haven't learned that in *any* topological space, the inverse image of an open set is *always* open.  That's how continuity is defined.  Obviously $(t, \infty)$ is open and $E$ is the inverse image of that open set, so it's necessarily open.  The proof below doesn't rely on any of this.

Comment: By definition, preimages of open sets under continuous mappings are open.  Now $E$ is the preimage of $(t,\infty)$ under $f$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Not sure, of course, but my guess is that the original poster hasn't yet reached that general topological definition of continuity.  That's why I provided an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose $x_0 \in E$.  Then $f(x_0)=t+a$, where $a \gt 0$.  Define $\epsilon = \frac{a}{2}$.  Since $f$ is continuous, $\exists \delta \gt 0$ such that $|x-x_0| \lt \delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)| \lt \epsilon \Rightarrow f(x) \gt t \Rightarrow x \in E.$  Thus, the entire open interval $(x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta) \subseteq E$.  Since $x_0 \in E$ was arbitrary, this proves that E is open.

Comment: $E$ may be empty ...

Comment: True, but if it's empty then it's open by definition.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested above, you can try to prove that the complement is closed. Let $(x_n)$ be sequence converging towards $x$ belonging to the complement of $E$, then we have $f(x_n) \leq t$. By continuity, at the limit, we have $f(x) \leq x$, which proves that $x$ belongs to the complement of $E$, which therefore is closed

Comment: The complement may be empty ...

Comment: Sure, but then $E=R$ and would be open